# How to use CSS grid for a fixed nav and fluid content area like the wireframe?

Tags: css, html, css-grid

[image: ...]

I've got a layout built that's similar to the illustration below, but I'm running into one problem. I want the content in the **nav** to be vertically aligned, and I want the main to behave as normal.

I also want to fix the **nav** in place, but as far as I know I can't do this with CSS grid. I have a working version that doesn't use CSS grid, but is there a way to achieve this with grid and get the vertical alignment the design requires?

```css
body {
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
  background: #CF0; /* green */
}

nav { 
  position: fixed;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;

  background: #CCC; /* light grey */
}

main {
  width: 70%;
  float: right;

  background: #333; /* dark grey */
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <nav>
        <h1>nav</h1>
        <p>needs to align all items in here vertically</p>
      </nav>
      <main>
        <h3>main</h3>
        <p>how do you turn this into css grid</p>
      </main>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you describe what we are seeing in the image? Is the second view what you currently get with css grid layout or what you want to achieve with css grid layout?

Comment: I changed the image, I realized that was misleading (the other view was mobile) -- this image should show two states, one where the content is shorter than the browser window is tall, and the view when the content is taller than the browser window

Comment: you have not used any grid on your nav element. I think you can achive with the examples by Mozilla https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Box_Alignment_in_CSS_Grid_Layout

Comment: or better you can use flexbox if grid is not mandatory :)

Comment: @Manjunath Yeah, OP is specifically asking how he would write a CSS Grid layout that matches the functionality/design of his current code...

Comment: @riot So you want the sidebar to be the full height of the viewport and fixed, but you want the body/main part to scroll normally?

Comment: yea that's exactly right -- what's more, I'd like the content in the **nav** to stay vertically centered, no matter how much content there is

I could do a position: fixed for the nav, then add a bunch of markup to get the content vertically aligned and the rest is cake, but where's the fun in that?